# Quick question regarding the proving or disproving that $\Bbb R^3[x]=\operatorname{span}\{1,x+x^2,4x^3,2x\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

So I am trying to prove or dispove that $\Bbb R^3[x] = \operatorname{span} \{1,x+x^2,4x^3+x^2,2x\}$. From what I understand, all I need to do to disprove this is show that $\{1,x+x^2,4x^3+x^2,2x\}$ are linearly dependent. I have two questions regarding this:

1. Am I allowed to multiply by $x$?

EXAMPLE: $3x^3\cdot(1)+x\cdot(x+x^2)-(4x^3+x^2)+0\cdot (2x)=3x^3+x^2+x^3-4x^3-x^2=0$

2. If the span is larger that the size of the space, as it is in this case, does everything in the span need to be linearly independent, or is sufficient that a number equal to the size of the space is linearly independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allowed to multiply by elements of the base field, which seems to be $\Bbb R$ here. So no, you can't multiply by $x$.

To solve this problem, you can write the coefficients of the four polynomials as a matrix, and compute its determinant (note that this matrix is square). If it is not $0$, the rank of the matrix is $4$ and therefore, the polynomials span $\Bbb R^3[x]$.

Comment: Should the "vectors" be placed vertically or horizontally in the matrix?

Comment: It doesn't matter. $\det(A)=\det(A^t)$ for every square matrix $A$.

Comment: Ok what about the other part of the question?

Comment: Well, the span can't be larger than the space. If this happened, it would not be a space.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $1, x, x^3\in\text{span}\{1,x+x^2,4x^3,2x\}$ since $x=1/2(2x)$ and $x^3=1/4(4x^3)$. Also we have that $$x^2=(x+x^2)-x\in\text{span}\{1,x+x^2,4x^3,2x\}.$$
Thus
$$
\mathbb{R}^3[x]=\text{span}\{1, x, x^2,x^3\}\subseteq \text{span}\{1,x+x^2,4x^3,2x\}
$$
where $\mathbb{R}^3[x]$ is the polynomials of degree at most $3$ over the real numbers. The result follows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following lemma:

> If the set $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ is linearly dependent and $x_1 \ne 0$, then there exists $j \in \{2, \ldots, n\}$ such that $x_j \in \operatorname{span}\{x_1, \ldots, x_{j-1}\}$.

Proof: There exist scalars $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$ not all equal to zero such that $\alpha_1x_1 + \ldots + \alpha_nx_n = 0$. Let $\alpha_j$ be the last nonzero scalar. Then $$x_j = -\frac{\alpha_1}{\alpha_j}x_1 - \ldots - -\frac{\alpha_{j-1}}{\alpha_j}x_{j-1}$$

so $x_j \in \operatorname{span}\{x_1, \ldots, x_{j-1}\}$.

Now arrange your set as $\{1, 2x, x + x^2, 4x^3\}$. The first element is $\ne 0$ and every element cannot be written as a linear combination of its predecessors because the polynomials in the set have strictly increasing degrees.

Using the lemma, we conclude that $\{1, 2x, x + x^2, 4x^3\}$ is linearly independent, and furthermore since $\dim \Bbb R^3[x] = 4$, it is a basis for $\Bbb R^3[x]$. So $\Bbb R^3[x] = \operatorname{span}\{1, 2x, x + x^2, 4x^3\}$.

Answer (score 0):

The systematic way is to compute the rank of the matrix whose rows are the coordinates of the elements of the set with respect to the canonical basis $1,x,x^2,x^3$.

The set generates the space iff the rank equals the dimension of the space. In your example, you want the rank to be 4. The rank of a matrix can be found using Gaussian elimination.

The matrix in your case is
$$
\pmatrix{
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 4 \\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0
}
$$